# Bash Script - If GREP result = then

Tags: bash, macos, grep

I can see some grep/if/bash stuff out there but i'm struggling to pull it together for my example on OS X.

Basically I want to run the following command

```
diskutil info "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" | grep "Device Block Size"
```

Which searches the Macintosh HD on a system for the Device Block Size if it comes back as 512 Bytes I want it to run one command, if it comes back at 4096 Bytes I want it to run a different command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
block_size=$(diskutil info "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" | grep "Device Block Size" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
if [[ "$block_size" = 512 ]]; then
    echo 512
elif [[ "$block_size" = 4096 ]]; then
    echo 4096
else
    echo neither
fi
```

However, let me point out that this is not very portable for various reasons:

- The start volume might not be named `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`
- The computer might be set to a different language so it might not print it in english
- Apple might change the format
- ...

I'd suggest to use something similar to the following instead:

```
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/.diskutil_XXXXXX)
diskutil info -plist / >> "$tmp"
block_size=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :DeviceBlockSize' "$tmp")
rm "$tmp"
if [[ "$block_size" = 512 ]]; then
    echo 512
elif [[ "$block_size" = 4096 ]]; then
    echo 4096
else
    echo neither
fi
```

Comment: Ho Johannes, thats great - don't worry too much about the variables this is for a fixed environment for now with always the same name and it works perfectly! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You can extract size using awk and then use if/elseif conditions:

```
size=$(diskutil info "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" | awk '/Device Block Size/{print $(NF-1)}')

if [[ $size -eq 512 ]]; then
   echo "eecuting command for size = 512 ..."
elif [[ $size -eq 512 ]]; then
   echo "eecuting command for size = 4096 ..."
fi
```